# How to do a TM backup so that you can do a FULL restore using OSX utilities?

Tags: backup, time-machine, restore

I patched my older MBP to Monterey 12.6 and have a current Time Machine backup.  When I rebooted it failed and I used Command R to get to a screen that allowed access to my drives.

It didn't allow me to do a restore from my TM backup, something about it not being a full backup.

I'm not sure what qualifies for a backup that I can restore from using the Command R.  My backup excludes files that I don't see as important, but I'd like to have a full backup.  How can I do this with Time Machine so that the OSX Utilities will see it, not just the OS?

Comment: Which files/folders did you exclude?

Comment: I have a feeling Monterey doesn't backup the current system drive, only data - so it might depend on what OS you're trying to restore. You may need to do a fresh internet recovery install, then migrate in the Time Machine, rather than recover from it. Make sure when you do this that you're putting the same OS on the drive as was on before, nothing earlier, otherwise Time Machine will refuse to migrate. [Apple seem to be trying to make macOS more & more like iOS, where the system & apps are restored from the cloud, rather than your own backup.]

Comment: nohillside the directory "applications" was excluded because I figured it would save time and space.  Having the data is the most important thing, but I'd like to know how to install the OS from the backup.  The apps dir is 40G and includes Xcode, so I figured I didn't really need to back that up.  I assumed the OS was included in the backup, but maybe there's some setting for that?

Comment: @KarlJay If you exclude things like /Applications then it makes sense it would prohibit a restore, since that includes things like Safari (in Monterey). You probably could've excluded just Xcode and it would work, but I'm not sure.